# Outlook quick launch icon has caution sign - no new e-mails have arrived

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Microsoft Outlook for e-mail. For no particular reason a few days ago a caution sign appeared on the quick launch icon. I thought nothing of it until I realized I have received no e-mail for four days, the probability of which is close to zero.

[image]

I have searched for this problem's solution but to no avail. No warning messages are displayed anywhere else. If any of you have any idea what the problem is I would appreciate it!

Comment: If it shows a warning icon, it should also say what's wrong.  I'm getting it now, without that explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to check is if you are still logged in to the account (if you are at home). Sometimes a session can time out and you would have to re-log-in.

Basic troubleshooting questions:

1. What changes were made in the last four days (since the problem began)?
2. Have you rebooted?

If you made a change to an AV application (like Dave M suggested) it could cause this. If you made any network changes at all - moved the Exchange server, installed a firewall etc - this could affect the network.

I suggested rebooting in the event that this was session based. Closing the application and reopening it would do the same thing. How do you log in? Is it SSO or are you prompted for credentials when you open Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

This normally means it can't connect to the email server. Check your account settings and verify that you are able to reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

This might indicate an account error such as a bad password or other issue related to conectiong to the mail server..  Is that possible?  Are there any errors when you click Send/Receive in Outlook?

Is this connected to an Exchange Server? If so, have you contacted the Exchange Administrator.

AV applications can create this issue as well.  Are you running an AV app that scans e-mail?  Have also seen malware cause this issue.  Are you sure there are no infections?

Check event logs for possible clues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because my password was changed because it was about to expire.  I restarted Outlook it prompted me for my new password, and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue appeared after using my company VPN. I fixed it by opening Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings and unchecking "Use a proxy server for your LAN". Then I restarted Outlook and it worked!

This also solved an issue I was having with Microsoft Teams, where I got a "can't connect to the internet" error. Strangely enough all other internet browsing/services worked.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple. Its just because of the password issue. The password usually gets expired after certain days.

All we need to do is renew the password and login again. Try restarting outlook at the end. It worked in my case.